# Issue with gitignore negating a directory but then re-including a file within a sub directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I am having problems with ignoring a directory but then re-including a file within a sub-directory of the same directory I've ignored.

- **WORKS**

Folder Setup:

```
folder/
   commit-me.txt
   ignore-me.txt
```

.gitignore:

```
folder/*
!folder/commit-me.txt
```

---

- **DOESN'T WORK**

Folder Setup:

```
folder/
   sub/
       commit-me.txt
       ignore-me.txt
   ignore-me.txt
```

.gitignore:

```
folder/*
!folder/sub/commit-me.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git isn't smart enough to un-ignore the subdirectory because you unignored a file inside of it.

This works:

```
folder/*
folder/sub/*
!folder/sub/
!folder/sub/commit-me.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Until you're in to at least hundreds of folders, the easiest thing to do is probably to add `!*/` to the end if your `.gitignore`.  That will stop git completely ignoring any entire directory unless you later tell it otherwise.  So yours would be

```
folder/**
!folder/sub/commit-me.txt
!*/
```

The later `!*/` specification tells git that no matter what you said before, it should examine directory contents.  So since git doesn't track directories, it only cares about them as pathname components for actual content, it not ignoring a directory won't itself cause anything to be committed, it will only have git not skip any (previously matched) directories during its search.

The `**` means "match any number of directory levels here too" and since git 1.8.4 the matching is done by git itself so it's guaranteed to work everywhere.

When you're using `!*/` to avoid whole-directory ignores the difference between `*` and `**` is important: the `folder/*` will only match names directly within `folder` -- it *never* matched filenames within subfolders, but since ignoring a folder ignores its entire contents this wasn't apparent.

Once you've played along with [the gitignore rules](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) in a few different situations they make good sense, and if you're after understanding that they wind up a much better source to learn from than any prose description I've ever seen.

Comment: Sorry @justinhoward pipped you to answering although your solution works and your syntax is cleaner

Comment: No worries, wouldn't say it was a bad call since I might have done the same.

Comment: Cool. Can you clarify what the double star does in your answer?

Comment: It means "match any number of directory levels here too".  Strictly speaking it's an extension, so far as I know it works everywhere.  Without that the wildcard would only apply directly within `folder`, and so content in other subdirectories would be exposed by the `!*/`  and no longer ignored rather than never even being checked when their containing directories were ignored.

Comment: (updating the comment above: since git 1.8.4 matching is done by git itself so `**` matching is guaranteed supported everywhere.)

Comment: Good explanation. If you're expecting folders you're ignoring to likely have sub-directories which you also want to ignore, is it good practice to always use the double star syntax (especially since it's widely supported)?